# Disable scrollbar in ScrollView while entering large text

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-scrollview, android-scrollbar

I have an activity that contains scrollView>linearLayout>edittext
And I want to disable the scroll of the ScrollView so that the user can enter texts as much as he wants.
I tried many solutions but none of them worked for me:
XMLfile:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/logout_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/logout_toolbar"
        android:elevation="5sp"
        ></include>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:weightSum="1">


            <include
                android:id="@+id/description_toolbar"
                layout="@layout/description_toolbar"
                android:elevation="5sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></include>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/addDescription"
                android:lines="10"
                android:maxLines="400"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="40sp"
                android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:hint="Add your description here." />


            <Switch
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Choice Number 01  "
                android:id="@+id/switch1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
                android:textOff="No"
                android:textOn="Yes"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <Switch
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Choice Number 02  "
                android:id="@+id/switch2"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
                android:textOff="No"
                android:textOn="Yes"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:checked="false" />

            <Switch
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Choice Number 03  "
                android:id="@+id/switch3"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
                android:textOff="No"
                android:textOn="Yes"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:checked="false" />

            <Switch
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Choice Number 04  "
                android:id="@+id/switch4"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
                android:textOff="No"
                android:textOn="Yes"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:checked="false" />

            <Switch
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Choice Number 05  "
                android:id="@+id/switch5"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
                android:textOff="No"
                android:textOn="Yes"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:checked="false" />

            <Switch
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Choice Number 06  "
                android:id="@+id/switch6"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
                android:textOff="No"
                android:textOn="Yes"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:checked="false" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="188dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Next"
                android:id="@+id/btnNext"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

JAVAfile:

```
        @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.addDescription) {
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            switch (event.getAction()&MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsXSf.png

Comment: what is happening for now, couldn't understand.

Comment: Normally, when I enter a lot of text only the edittext scrollbar work, but here in my case both scrollbars are working together

Comment: set some left and right margin to your edittext and add android:maxlines=10

Comment: that does disable Scrollbar of ScrollView when EditText is selected.

Comment: no it will not, but both cannot be scrolled at same time as you mentioned because edittext has its own scrollview. want more info. ?

Comment: That's what is happing in my case. Both at the same time

Comment: remove this line android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset" and set some maxlines like 8.

Comment: you are using android:maxLines="400" and width as match parent thats why its happening.

Comment: Why do I have to set it to 8, the text maybe longer than 8 lines. But the problem isn't in the EditText, my problem is in the ScrollView, how to disable its scrollbar when the EditText is on selected

Comment: i dont know why you are trying to disable the scroll view because there is a big text of around 400 and if scrollview is disabled then how will you scroll the other items of the page because there is not space will left after 400 lines.later you can't enable it

Comment: You can hide scroll bar forever via android:scrollbars="none" 

     <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:fillViewport="true">

Comment: I don't want to hide forever because i have a lot of views. I just want to hide it or disable it when EditText is selected